# configuring _JAVA_OPTIONS for remote debug, I always get ERROR: JDWP

Tags: java, clojure, jvm

Good day, I'm trying debug my code, It's a clojure code using vertx lein...generally I use

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

and this works perfect, but I don't know why these JAVA_OPTS are ignored when I use a [lein vertx project](https://github.com/isaiah/lein-vertx), basically the remote debugger doesn't start

searching here in stackoverflow I found than I could use _JAVA_OPTIONS instead, now when I run my project seems than my jvm takes the options perfectly but fails after open the socket

```
lein vertx run
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 4000
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_
```

this is not an issue related to the port address, I've tried with 7000,5050,5000,9000,4848,48148,18787 and with every address It's fails...also I tried check what app is using the port

```
netstat -ap | grep 18787
```

and it's empty, basically any app is using the same port...

Also I try adding the jvm_opts to my project.clj

```
:jvm-opts ["-Xdebug" "-Xnoagent" "-Djava.compiler=NONE" "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n"]
```

it doesnt works neither...
these are some options than I tested before

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket, address=1043, server=y, suspend=n"
--- src/yvertx3 » export JVM_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket, address=1043, server=y, suspend=n"

export JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n"


export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n"

export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999" 

export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n"

export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n $JAVA_OPTS"
```

any clue will be appreciate...thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you are using are only setting the `dt_socket` port. To fix this error you should change the port used by the vertx server itself.